# Is a low-energy cruise an option for manned lunar flights?

Tags: the-moon, crewed-spaceflight, trajectory, launch-vehicle

Some lunar probes such as GRAIL travelled on a different trajectory to the Moon that went even much farther than the Moon itself is from Earth, to a Langrangian point, so why isn't this option ever brought up for human Moon missions? It takes weeks to reach the Moon by that, but on the ISS astronauts are spending much longer times. And such cruise wouldn't require a carrier rocket as strong as the Saturn V / SLS, or does it for human flights? Wouldn't a Falcon 9 or Falcon Heavy suffice for such low-energy cruise?

Comment: "so why isn't this option ever brought up for human Moon missions?" Life support and other consumables.

Comment: @OrganicMarble So how did astronauts survive for more than two months on SkyLab?

Comment: They weren't launched to the moon carrying all their consumables along.

Comment: "such cruise wouldn't require a carrier rocket as strong as the Saturn V" - most of the mass of the Saturn V was needed to get the Apollo stack to orbit. Only about 1/30th of its propellant and engine power was used for the trans-lunar injection burn.

Comment: @Nullnummer Falcon 9 is already suited for moon mission, without low energy cruise.

Comment: @ColonelCornieliusCornwall It's spelled "Cornelius" BTW

Answer (score 7):

You would only save a bit more fuel by doing that if you sent a probe. If you send humans on a longer mission then you will have to have more food, water and oxygen. Overall you will need more fuel to ship everything the humans would need to survive the longer trip. Also we could send humans around the world on zeppelins and save a lot of fuel doing that, but airplanes are preferred because they are much faster. Time is an important factor when humans are onboard.

Comment: People are for six months on the ISS. Wouldn't a Space Shuttle-like space glider be able to carry more supply?

Comment: @Nullnummer Shipping food to low Earth orbit is a lot cheaper than shipping it to the moon.

Comment: The ISS receives a lot of resupply shipments. In the next 12 months there are [at least 10 planned cargo shipments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Fleet_operations), plus whatever supplies are on the crew rotation vehicles. Sending supply shipments to a vessel in transit to the moon would be... nontrivial.

Comment: @Cadence Cygnus freighter + SLS = space food!

Comment: @The Rocket Fan you are correct. time is important, because unlike probes, us humans have families and lives we gotta get back to. Would you rather get more times in space or have more time with those you care about. Yeah, I know I'm a good speaker.

Comment: @ColonelCornieliusCornwall ISS astronauts are seperated from their loved ones for six months and some even for a year (Polyakov, Kelly). Btw I'd rather be in space _and_ have my loved ones in space too. Would be better for us all, to be off the planet.

Comment: The ISS is also very large compared to most plausible transport vehicles.

Comment: The whole point of the ISS (and Skylab before it) was to be up there for long periods. As a side note, this allows most of the essential non-human cargo to be delivered on (cheaper/riskier) flights.

Comment: @Nullnummer great point.

Answer (score 5):

Comparison to Salyut, Skylab, Mir, ISS, and Tiangong is a bit inapt as all of those space stations operate within the thermosphere. The Earth's upper atmosphere and the Earth's magnetic field protect the inhabitants of those space stations from some space radiation.

Moreover, those space stations had escape mechanisms for a quick return to Earth in case something goes very wrong. The Apollo missions had a semi-quick return option in case something went wrong. This was used on Apollo 13, where something went drastically wrong. What if something goes seriously wrong on your proposed slow transfer to the Moon?

Answer (score 2):

A "low-energy cruise" is probably better known as a [**ballistic lunar transfer** (BLT)](https://advancedspace.com/blt/). These trajectories generally require *more* $\Delta V$ from the launch vehicle, but less of the payload (spacecraft), though the use of an outbound lunar flyby makes the launch C3 comparable to a direct lunar transfer (at cost of extended transfer times):

[image: c3 vs spacecraft dV, advanced space]

(Credit: [Advanced Space](https://advancedspace.com/blt/))

The $\Delta V$ savings are significant on the payload side, but overall not as much. A crewed lunar mission still necessitates a super heavy lift launch vehicle.

Also note that a BLT does not travel to a Lagrangian point but rather uses the relative strength of the Sun's gravitational pull (being so far from the Earth and the Moon) to raise the spacecraft's "Earthian" perigee to a similar height as the Moon.

See Also: [My answer to "Is there a fairly detailed outline of CAPSTONE's "highly efficient ballistic lunar transfer trajectory" from LEO to lunar near-rectilinear halo orbit?"](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58542/40257)