# Station-keeping delta-v per year for an Earth-Moon vanilla halo orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, delta-v, station-keeping, halo-orbit, three-body

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49014) reminds us that an Earth-Moon L1 or L2 vanilla<sup>1</sup> halo orbit remaining always visible to some patch on the Moon's surface requires station-keeping.

[Queqiao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4#Queqiao) uses such an orbit having continuous visibility with both Chang'e 4 on the Moon's far side and with Earth.

**Question:** Roughly how much station-keeping delta-v per year would be required for such an Earth-Moon halo orbit? This must have been worked out long ago, perhaps in "[DoKaRoMo?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49016/12102)"

---

**note:** For comparison, JWST will be in a vanilla halo orbit about the Sun-Earth L2 position and require only about 2.4 m/s per year for station-keeping! This is due to some clever balancing of solar radiation pressure and bi-weekly calculations and station-keeping maneuvers.

- [What is the required burn to keep a satellite at a Lagrangian point?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36276/12102)
- [Could JWST stay at L2 "forever"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35404/12102)
- [What happens to JWST after it runs out of propellant?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23238/12102)

It's likely that an Earth-Moon halo orbit will require much more due to the Moon's eccentric and inclined orbit with respect to both Earth's equator and its orbital plane.

---

<sup>1</sup>vanilla meaning those proposed by Bob Farquhar ([1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43708/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27412/12102), [3](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19710021579), [4](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43710/12102)) and [demonstrated numerically](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/kathleen.howell.1/Publications/Journals/1984_CM_How.pdf) by [Kathleen Connor Howell](https://engineering.purdue.edu/Engr/People/ptProfile?resource_id=1384) and not a near-rectilinear halo orbit ([1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24019/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23992/12102)) or a butterfly orbit ([3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41870/12102)).

See also Farquhar, R. W.: "The Control and Use of Libration-Point Satellites", Ph.D. Dissertation, Dept. of Aeronautics and Astronautics, Stanford University, Stanford, California, 1968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to leave this is a comment because I don't have a great answer, but I ran into a character limit with hyperlinks.

Sadly I can't give a specific answer for non-NRHO halos. But I did find [this source](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/isee-3), which mentions that ISEE-3 (the first mission to go to a Halo orbit) used about 8 m/s per year of delta-V for stationkeeping. This mission was in a Sun-Earth Halo, though.

I *can* tell you that stationkeeping costs increase as stability index increases (higher stab index means more unstable). See Section 5.1.1 and Figures 5.2-5.3 [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/kathleen.howell.1/Publications/Masters/2017_Zimovan.pdf) for more context on stability index in the Halos. Dan Grebow has published some DV numbers for stationkeeping, shown in table 5.8 [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/people/kathleen.howell.1/Publications/Masters/2006_Grebow.pdf). I'm sure there are more sources out there but these are what I could find quickly.

Comment: This is an excellent start, thanks! From time to time "too long for a comment" yet very helpful answers are well received here, and I think this counts as one. I've never heard of *stability index* but I will go ahead and read about it now.